# XCode + Selenium

Tags: xcode, macos, selenium, cocoa

I am trying to build a native macOS app that interacts with a browser.

Doing this with other languages has been easy (Python and C# for example), but I am having trouble finding information on how to get the same thing working natively in macOS. I have also been able to run a console application using Visual Studio for Mac, but I end up with a .exe file that does not serve its purpose, and using nuget to develop a cocoa app always shows me the following error (maybe due to the referenced file being different from the one I am using at runtime):

```
Could not resolve type with token 010000b3 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform, netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
```

I don't see any information on how to include chrome or firefox drivers and starting up the browser, as well as comunicating with the browser for interaction.

I am very new to macOS, XCode, Swift and Cocoa, so any information with details or sample code on how to achieve this would be welcome.

Comment: Not sure but might help - https://www.utest.com/articles/selenium-setup-on-a-mac-and-configuring-selenium-webdriver-on-mac-os

Comment: @Prany no, that doesn't help. it is a setup based on java, it is for setting up selenium server which is not the purpose, and I had already seen that. I am looking for something as simple as this: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/set-up-selenium-webdriver-with-visual-studio-in-c/ Just the necessary references and code to launch the browser in mac.